# Why Isn't My Bridged Method Being Called Properly?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, react-native

I'm creating a bridge from `iOS` to `React Native` for `HomeKit`. I'm currently just getting started and simply trying to create a Home for test purposes. I've successfully accepted permissions for HomeKit as set in the `info.plist` aka `NSHomeKitUsageDescription`.

## RNHomeKit.m

```
#import "RNHomeKit.h"
#import <HomeKit/HomeKit.h>
#import <React/RCTLog.h>

@implementation RNHomeKit

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(createHome) {
  RCTLog(@"FAKELY CREATING HOME");
  HMHomeManager *myHomeManager = [[HMHomeManager alloc] init];

  [myHomeManager addHomeWithName: @"Matt's Awesome Home" completionHandler:^(HMHome *home, NSError *error) {
    RCTLog(@"REALLYING CREATING HOME");
    if (!error) {
      RCTLog(@"Created Home : %@",home.name);
    } else {
      RCTLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
  }];
}

@end
```

## RNHomekit.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <HomeKit/Homekit.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RNHomeKit : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>

@end
```

I'm calling my `createHome` method on my homescreen's `componentDidMount()` using `RNHomeKit.createHome();`. `FAKELY CREATING HOME` is being logged, whereas `REALLYING CREATING HOME` is never seen. Why am I not hitting the `addHomeWithName`?

Comment: It depends on how you implement `addHomeWithName`. Are you sure it's not called? Since you log it inside callback of `completionHandler`, it might be called just without completion.

Comment: `addHomeWithName` is a function from `HMHomeManager` [Link to docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/homekit/hmhomemanager/1616747-addhomewithname?language=objc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried reverse engineering a Native HomeKit example app and made some changes that allowed it to work. An explanation as to why my original implementation didn't work would be great though!

## RNHomeKit.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <HomeKit/Homekit.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RNHomeKit : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule, HMHomeManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) HMHomeManager *myHomeManager;

@end
```

## RNHomeKit.m

```
#import "RNHomeKit.h"
#import <HomeKit/HomeKit.h>
#import <React/RCTLog.h>

@implementation RNHomeKit

@synthesize myHomeManager;

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(createHome) {
  RCTLog(@"FAKELY CREATING HOME");
  self.myHomeManager = [[HMHomeManager alloc] init];
  self.myHomeManager.delegate= self;

  [self.myHomeManager addHomeWithName: @"Matt's Awesome Home" completionHandler:^(HMHome *home, NSError *error) {
    RCTLog(@"REALLYING CREATING HOME");
    if (!error) {
      RCTLog(@"Created Home : %@",home.name);
    } else {
      RCTLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
  }];
}

@end
```